# Auth Middleware reroutes to a wrong signin page auth.signin

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 5.1 and i have applied an Auth middleware to a route, it works except my auth page is: /signin Not what it reroutes to /Auth.signin

I had deleted the default Auth folder and recreated my own inside app/Http/Controllers

Comment: Have you tried?
php artisan make:auth
php artisan migrate

Comment: Please explain what that would do...i am still learning laravel and have been avoiding using 'artisan' - i would prefer altering source code as opposed to running commands

Comment: This will create the routes and Controllers from Laravel Auth.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication

Comment: Remember i already have routes associated with my AuthController - the problem is how the 'Auth' Middleware works when applied to a route. Instead of taking me to my /signin route it defaults into /auth.signin and then return an laravel 404 page

Comment: Ok i solved it by going to the /Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php and changed this part of the code:

                  return redirect()->guest('auth.signin');

To:

                                  return redirect()->guest('signin');

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved it by going to the /Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php and changed this part of the code:

```
              return redirect()->guest('auth.signin');
```

To:

```
              return redirect()->guest('signin');
```